# Different Application Size On Different Screens

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

First time i'm developing a Windows Form Application with C# . I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

My form's size = 1096x508. Also i set Minimum Size and Maximum Size properties to 1096x508 .

This is screenshot of my app , 
[image]

But when i execute this app on another computer, result like this :

[image]

As you see, red line (at bottom of app) invisible. Because applciation's height is 508 px (as expected) on my pc but 416px on other computer. Because of this , red line staying out of Form. So we couldn't see it.

In shortly, my Form's size 1096x508px but it's only 823x416px on another computer. Can you tell me why there are difference? And how can i fix this? There are resolution difference between this screens.

Comment: @HansPassant you're right. But i couldn't understood accepted answer.

Comment: Changing AutoScaleMode to none seems fixed my problem. But you said "Changing the form's AutoScaleMode property is not a fix" . Why it's not a fix?

Comment: He's basically saying to make sure your application can handle resizes, and not to assume that it will always be the same size. He talks about the Dock and Anchor properties, which are Control properties that speficy how controls should handle resizing, lists off several controls that can be helpful for doing so (the panels), and also mentions that you can use the Resize event for extreme cases.

Comment: It's not a fix because it can lead to the text on the controls being partially cut off.

Comment: @MikePrecup i should study on Dock and Anchor properties . Now I will read a few articles about them. As you see, i have really little texts on my application, so can we say, this is a good fix *for this app*. Or still i need to use Dock or Anchor? Thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant if you send same answer to here, i'll accept. Thank you for your assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue, as you have already discovered, is that computers with a different DPI setting will cause the controls to scale.

What Hans was suggesting [in his linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558048/net-controls-changing-size-between-computers) is that you need to re-design your form so when it gets re-size messages it will handle them accordingly.

The main way this is normally handled is setting the [`Anchor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) or the [`Dock` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) of a control. By default a control will anchor to the top left corner of it's parent container. When it is told to scale it scales down and to the right. By changing the anchor point to be the bottom only it will make your bottom control move up instead of moving down off of the boundaries of the parent.

Comment: But it was `Anchor`ed to top left. And still there was problem.

Comment: Yes, you need to change it from top left to bottom (or bottom left). Also I assume you are doing some kind of math and setting the position of the control to make the paddle is move left and right? If so you need to make sure that it too is using references to the bottom of the parent instead of the top to figure its math too.

Comment: Oh now i understood. If i set Anchor to bottom, should i remain AutoScaleMode as default (Font) ? Or set to None ?

Comment: I would leave it as default. But you need to Test, making the code compile is only 50% of the job. You need to make sure that it works correctly in all situations. Test possible settings and if they don't work, don't use them. If you find a test case that causes it to break and you run out of ideas of things to try to fix it feel free to post another question here, that's what this is is for :)

Comment: This is enough for me. Thank you for your assist :) But i'm waiting Hans. He was first. If he didn't send an answer, i'll accept this one . I hope you understand me :)

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of your application on those computers may be caused by different dpi (dot-per-inch) settings of the Windows operating system. In order to check that please compare the actuals values in Windows display settings (100%, 125%, ...).
If you want to have your program independent from dpi settings you may try to work with different panels (control containers). Your status bar could have a fixed with, while the game area is a docked panel (filling the remaining space).
In general, staying independent from actual dpi, is a difficult topic. Most of the time you can work with autosizing controls, but you could run out of space if, say, two labels overlay.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand. How can i change it?

Comment: I thought it is obvious - but if you downvote without asking first then let's forget it.

Comment: I didn't vote this answer, yet.

Comment: I down-voted. To someone new to these concepts just telling them "it's the dpi" does them no good. Please go in to either how to fix it or where he should go to get more information on how to fix it, after that I will remove my downvote. (I also left a comment but Eray left his so I deleted mine.)

Comment: I couldn't see your comment Scott.

Comment: Well, don't know how to write it much better: go system settings (Windows!), look in display settings (don't know exactly what it is called in your language) and compare between both computers if there's any difference. It's dpi, or dots per inch.
And then for the other wise guy, who didn't understand what you're meant to do: change the setting such that it has the same value on both computers - obviously you have to copy from the working settings...

Comment: @Eray You posted about 3 seconds after mine, I deleted mine right away, you likely just never refreshed. (also be sure to include a @ before somones name, otherwise it does not notify the user you responed to them)

Comment: @JeffRSon Requireing all computers that use this program to have a DPI of 100% is a bad idea IMHO, and while I would not downvote an answer with that, I would never upvote one. (Also I can't remove my downvote till you EDIT your post, not just post a comment)

Comment: @Scott - sometimes one just needs some hint. He may be new to WinForms, but the hint for dpi (and display settings) referred to Windows. Maybe this wasn't too obvious on second sight.

Comment: But your solution of "Change the dpi back to 100" is a bad answer IMHO, I am writing up my own.

Comment: @Scott: I did not recommend this as a solution - I was trying to help where the difference between the computers could be found. Programming DPI independently is in general a rather difficult topic. I fully agree with you that forcing to 100% is not desirable.

Comment: ["change the setting such that it has the same value on both computers - obviously you have to copy from the working settings..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378414/different-application-size-on-different-screens#comment23472569_16378496) I think that is recommending a solution.

Comment: Much better, -1 removed.

Comment: ... in order to see if it works. Don't be too picky. It's completely clear, that you cannot force every computer in the world that this program should run on to a certain setting.